# Built in function that returns the type of its input

Tags: pascal

I'm beginning to learn pascal, and for the life of me can't find a simple function that returns the type of its input.

If any of you know Python, then the function I'm looking for is the equivalent of `type(object)`.

Thank you for your help, I'm really surprised at how this wasn't easily findable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get there from here.  Pascal doesn't have introspection.

Either the function accepts a type or it doesn't it can't guess the type of its argument.  In pascal types are fixed at compile time, so there's no need for a function that can recognise objects.

Answer (score 1):

As said in a previous answer, Object Pascal is statically typed so you don't need this. However for objects (classes) you have the equivalent of `isinstance()` with the `is` operator.

```
program isop;

type
  TFoo = class(TObject)
  end;
  TBar = class(TObject)
  end;
  TBaz = class(TBar)
  end;

var
  Obj1, Obj2, Obj3: TObject;
  Baz: TBaz;
begin
  Obj1 := TFoo.Create;
  Obj2 := TBar.Create;
  Obj3 := TBaz.Create;

  writeln(Obj1 is TFoo);
  writeln(Obj1 is TBar);
  writeln(Obj1 is TBaz);
  writeln(Obj2 is TFoo);
  writeln(Obj2 is TBar);
  writeln(Obj2 is TBaz);
  writeln(Obj3 is TFoo);
  writeln(Obj3 is TBar);
  writeln(Obj3 is TBaz);

  if Obj1 is TBaz then // false
    Baz := TBaz(Obj1);
  // or
  if Obj3 is TBaz then // true
    Baz := Obj3 as TBaz;
end.
```

In some case (like here) you only know that instances are TObject (common ancestor for all classes). So you can dynamically cast later to the right class type after a verification with `is`.